# What image format are MNIST images?

Tags: image, machine-learning, computer-vision, mnist

I've unpacked the first image from the MNIST training set and I can access the `(28,28)` matrix.

[image]

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3  18  18  18 126 136
  175  26 166 255 247 127   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  30  36  94 154 170 253 253 253 253 253
  225 172 253 242 195  64   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  49 238 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 251
   93  82  82  56  39   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  18 219 253 253 253 253 253 198 182 247 241
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  80 156 107 253 253 205  11   0  43 154
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  14   1 154 253  90   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 139 253 190   2   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  11 190 253  70   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  35 241 225 160 108   1
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  81 240 253 253 119
   25   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  45 186 253 253
  150  27   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16  93 252
  253 187   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 249
  253 249  64   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  46 130 183 253
  253 207   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  39 148 229 253 253 253
  250 182   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  24 114 221 253 253 253 253 201
   78   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  23  66 213 253 253 253 253 198  81   2
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0  18 171 219 253 253 253 253 195  80   9   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0  55 172 226 253 253 253 253 244 133  11   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0 136 253 253 253 212 135 132  16   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

I want to do some image processing on it like converting to grayscale and then binarizing it (for machine learning), however I'm confused as to what kind of image format I'm dealing with. If this was a `(28, 28, 3)` it's obvious that it's an RGB image with `3` channels. However, this is a `(28, 28)` image with each pixel taking on a value in the discrete range `[0, 255]`, which is rather odd. Is this image already in gray scale and do I just have to normalize the pixel values? What exactly does normalization entail? Do I multiply the flattened vector by the scalar `1/(sum of all energy values)` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are 28x28 pixel grey-scale images with 8-bit quantization (hence the range [0-255]). The images were apparently binary black/white images but anti-aliasing during resizing caused them to have additional grey-scale values. See [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) for additional details.

Normally, you would normalize by dividing all values by 255 (not the sum of all pixel values).